Why am I getting a 503 error with HttpClient while Postman works for the same request in windows cpp win32?
I am using the C++ REST SDK (cpprestsdk) to send an HTTP GET request, but I keep getting a 503 Service Unavailable error. When I make the same request in Postman, it works fine and returns a 200 OK response.
Here is my code:
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

int main() {
    http_client client(U("https://example.com/api/endpoint"));

    http_request request(methods::GET);
    try {
        auto response = client.request(request).get();

        if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK) {
            auto body = response.extract_string().get();
            std::wcout << U("Response: ") << body << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::wcout << U("HTTP Error: ") << response.status_code() << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

When I run this, the output is:
HTTP Error: 503
In Postman, I send the same request to the same endpoint with the same headers, and it works correctly (returns 200 OK).

Please show the exact request you're sending in postman, they're obviously not the same otherwise it would work

GET request the URL from Postman
